# Select last option of a radio button

Tags: jquery, radio-button, selector

How can I select a radio button option if nothing is selected (no default value).
I try this but I only got the first option selected and in this case I need the second option of my radios.

```
if (!$("input[name='myName']:checked").val()) {
            console.log('Nothing is checked!');
            $("#myName").prop("checked", true);            
        }


<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.myName, true, new { data_bind = "checked: myName" }) @Resources.Yes</label>
<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.myName, false, new { data_bind = "checked: myName" }) @Resources.No</label>
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with only the HTML and JS - there is no need to post server code for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they both have the same ID the HTML is invalid.

You can give them a value as they are supposed to have and do

```
if (!$("input[name='myName']:checked").val()) {
  console.log('Nothing is checked!');
  $("input[name='myName'][value='No']").prop("checked",true);
 }
```

or access the DOM

```
if (!$("input[name='myName']:checked").val()) {
  console.log('Nothing is checked!');
  $("input[name='myName']")[1].checked=true;
}
```

Example:

```js
$("input[name='myName'][value='No']").prop("checked",true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" name="myName" value="Yes">Yes</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="myName" value="No">No</label>
```